# 404 Not Found after a long AJAX request

Tags: php, ajax, nginx, mootools, opensuse

I have a function that sends a large amount of emails out in one go.

Submit Form -> AJAX Request -> send emails function -> Echo a response

When the request takes around 30 seconds, all is well, my request returns the data I need and I can continue. When the request takes longer (around 2 minutes or more) the response comes back as a 404 Not found.

I've tried debugging the section of code that echo's my response, but it never gets hit.
Thought maybe it was timing out, so...
Tried increasing `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` in `php.ini`.
Tried increasing the `keepalive_timeout` in `nginx.confd`.

All of the emails are getting sent regardless of this `404`, my php file just doesn't send the response when the request is done (unless as previously stated it doesn't take long due to small batch of emails)

Website running with openSUSE 12.2, php-fpm 5.4, nginx, MooTools, no php framework
sending emails with PEAR mail::factory

Server wasn't set-up by me, I am a new employee at a company

Willing to attempt any suggestions...

Comment: Maybe there is a proxy in between that quits after 30 seconds and delivers 404 to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out my problem, NGINX had the following setting

```
fastcgi_read_timeout 120;
```

It was `timing out` my request. Realized it as I was writing my question and wrote `php-fpm`